# Book question positive square root on quantum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information

On p.86 Section 2.2.4 of the Quantum computation and quantum information book by Nielsen,

[image]

$M_{o}$ is defined as the positive square root of the positive operator. Is the "positive square root" necessary (as $\left|\psi_{i}\right>$ are orthonormal so $M_{0}^{\dagger} M_{0}=M_{0}$)?

If positive square root is required for $M_{o}$, why not for $M_{i}$?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: As far as I understand from the quoted text, $M_i$ and $M_0$ are orthogonal projectors ($M_0$ projects onto the orthogonal complement of the space spanned by the $\psi_i$) and thus their positive square root coincides with the operator itself. There is no reason here why one should use the square root.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Supposedly, the $M_i$ are POVM operators which need to satisfy $\sum M_i^\dagger M_i=I$, thus the square root.  In the case under consideration it is indeed not necessary. (And moreover, since the post-measurement state does not matter, any square root would do.)

Comment: Yes I agree with you...The point is that in the text it is clearly stated that the $M_i$ are orthogonal projectors and not just positive  operators.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch this is not a homework problem at all. Just out of curiosity when I was reading.

Comment: It's from a standard textbook, so I would consider it as a homework-type problem. Also, it does not become clear from your question which part you don't understand, and why not. (What were your thoughts on that?)

Comment: @Valter Moretti No. they are no projectors. They are general measurement operators. But in this particular example, ∣ψi⟩ are orthonormal so I don't think there is a need for positive square root. But if ∣ψi⟩ are not orthonormal, then there is a need. But if the author introduced square root to M0, why not for other Mi?

Comment: @kww You *do* realize that they *define* $M_i=\vert\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i\vert$, which *are* projectors? (And since the $\vert\psi_i\rangle$ are orthogonal, $M_0$ is as well?)

Comment: @kww Well, they are orthogonal projectors by construction. This is the technical reason why the square root is useless here.

Comment: @kww, I mean, in general they aren't, but here they are. Does your question concern this particular case or the general one?

Comment: @Valter Moretti Why only M0 has the square root form, but not for other Mi? What is the significance of square root form for M0 as I think it would not have been introduced if not for some special meaning (maybe for this particular example?). One will take square root to make a positive operator. But why is it needed for the definition of M0?

Comment: @Valter Moretti Is $M_{0}$ a projector? or, is $M_{0}^{\dagger}M_{0}$ a projector?

Comment: $M_0 = M_0^\dagger = M^\dagger_0M_0$ and $M_i = M_i^\dagger = M^\dagger_iM_i$....

Comment: @Valter Moretti But is that a sufficient condition for projector?

Comment: Sure. In a vector space $X$ a projector is defined as a linear map $P:X \to X$ such that $PP=P$. If $X$ is a Hilbert space, an *orthogonal projector* is a projector such that $P=P^\dagger$. There are other equivalent definitions base on the subspaces given by the images of the projectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying idea of the construction is that you are given a set of POVM measurement operators $M_1,\dots,M_n$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^n M_i^\dagger M_i\le 1$ which you want to complete to a complete POVM by adding an extra element (=outcome) $M_0$. Thus, $M_0$ needs to satisfy
$$
M_0^\dagger M_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n M_i^\dagger M_i = 1\ ,
$$
i.e., $M_0$ must be a square root of $1-\sum_{i=1}^n M_i^\dagger M_i$.

There is no particular reason to choose any specific square root. The only reason to choose the positive one could be because it is the simplest *specific* choice.

Also, since $M_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$ are *defined* in a specific way (here, for the purpopse of distinguishing a set of quantum states), there is no reason to define them as a square root of anything: They are just given to us, and all we need to find is an $M_0$ which completes them.